# RegEx help parsing a line

Tags: regex

I need the Regex to parse strings like this.

> Bag Jam Error #1100 - (OUTFEED) Bag Did Not Reach Outfeed

This error message will vary from line to line.

What would the RegEx be if I need the following broken out? As below in bold…

**02**|**05/28/2012 12:25:46.95** - ** ERROR ** - **Bag Jam Error #1100 - (OUTFEED) Bag Did Not Reach Outfeed** (last bag=**04085100000001**)

I want to extract

> 02|05/28/2012 12:25:46.95
>
> Bag Jam Error #1100 - (OUTFEED) Bag Did Not Reach Outfeed
>
> 04085100000001

Comment: Please be more precise. What does your input look like (don't add any markdown to it)? What do you want to capture? What, if anything, is different in the lines containing these errors from every other line?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Regex.Split("-**ERROR**-");
```

and

```
Regex.Split("-");
```

those two methods returns Array of string in first case u have

```
splittedArray[0]="02|05/28/2012 12:25:46.95";
splittedArray[1]="Bag Jam Error #1100 - (OUTFEED) Bag Did Not Reach Outfeed (last bag=04085100000001)";
```

Then Split spliteedArray[1] and you have

```
newSplittedArray[0]="Bag Jam Error #1100";
newSplittedArray[1]="(OUTFEED) Bag Did Not Reach Outfeed (last bag=04085100000001)";
```

Comment: Or u can use only

    Regex.Split("-");

and throw up variable that contains

    "**Error**"

second element of array;

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would let you grab the three parts.

```
(.*) - \*\* ERROR \*\* - (.*) \(lastbag=([0-9]*)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex assumes you are breaking the error into parts that look like this:

1. Bag Jam Error (short description)
2. 1100 (error number)
3. OUTFEED (unsure)
4. Bag Did Not Reach Outfeed (last bag=04085100000001) (the rest of the line)

It uses capture groups, which in most languages you can reference with `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4`.

```
(.*)#(\d+).*\((\w+)\)(.*$)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?) \- .*? \- (.*) \(last bag=([0-9]+)\)
```

Gives you these 3 matching groups...

1. 02|05/28/2012 12:25:46.95
2. Bag Jam Error #1100 - (OUTFEED) Bag Did Not Reach Outfeed
3. 04085100000001

Here it is in action:
https://regex101.com/r/oO8mR8/1